# Shouldn't Stack Overflow Careers have its own meta?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, per-site-meta

Almost every Stack Exchange site now has a meta. It seems that http://careers.stackoverflow.com should have one too.

PS: I'd ask in it: Why not include other Stack Exchange sites like https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Can't we handle Careers questions in the same way we do Area 51 and Stack Exchange Data Explorer? It even has its own tag here, which you've put on this question, and has been decently active in terms of feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three main reasons why Careers doesn't need its own Meta:

1. There's no "community" per se on Careers
2. The volume of questions is far too low to dedicate an entire site to it
3. Careers doesn't follow the model of a regular Stack Exchange site because it uses its own engine (i.e., it doesn't have questions and answers, reputation, etc.)

Meta Stack Overflow is sort of a catch-all for these one-off sites including Area 51, Data Explorer, StackApps, and the Stack Exchange home page (including the Reputation Leagues).

So any questions (support, discussion, bug, feature-request) you have about Careers can be directed here.