# Why is meta.SE the meta site for careers.SO?

Tags: discussion, jobs, scope

Tag [careers](/questions/tagged/careers) is quite active and recent "accepted" questions suggest that questions about careers.SO are ontopic here. This is supported by the fact that the footer on careers.SO links to meta.SE.

I wonder why that is.

1. careers.SO is a SO[FU]-only thing -- it only deals with programming jobs. The rest of the network has no relations with the portal.
2. `careers.stackexchange.com` does not even work, it's `careers.stackoverflow.com` (and rightly so).
3. careers.SO is not a Q&A and is thus not affected by network policy.

Therefore, I think it would be more appropriate to discuss careers.SO on meta.SO instead of meta.SE (or have its own meta) and such questions should be offtopic here.

Comment: Maybe they want to not be so short-sighted about Careers

Comment: Related: [Careers needs its own meta/dedicated support system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129688)

Comment: Careers is highlighted in the drop-down on Stack Overflow and Server Fault only, not Super User.

Comment: Well, before the MSO-MSE split there was not even a Stack Overflow specific meta *either*. Where *else* would you have put Careers.SO feature requests and bug reports?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: And that is exactly why I think now is the perfect time to talk about this! :D

Comment: Since Careers is *already* part of more than one site (SO *and* SF), why is Meta.SE not a good fit for this?

Comment: _"careers.SO is a SO[FU]-only"_ -- in my experience this ain't so, I put quite a lot of stuff from Programmers.SE there. Consider [edit]ing to account for that

Comment: @gnat The top bar does not link to careers.SO on [programmers.SE] and that's what I based my post on; of course, you might happen upon programmers on any site. The connection with [programmers.SE] seems obvious, though, agreed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar concerns starting out.

I don't believe Careers naturally fits either meta site perfectly as it's laid out in the [original post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own) describing the split. If we continue down a path of closer integration with Stack Overflow and Careers, then making the switch would seem appropriate.  For now, I haven't been able to muster up a convincing argument why one is better than the other, so I'm happy as long as we continue to see interest and support from the community.

Careers for now is part of the larger Stack Exchange network, even if it isn't a Q&A site.  If that changes, then Careers meta location will change as well.

Comment: In that case, please consider this one vote against "support from the community". :)

Comment: Why not having a standalone discussion zone for Careers, same way Area 51 got its own? Employers who come here might get unpleasant surprise if they are not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Careers is a major revenue stream, so I don't see why they/we would want to shut the doors to extending it to other areas. Apart from Programmers mentioned above, just look at all the other sites mentioned under 'Technology' in the footnotes.

*I'd say the more logical thing to do would be to rename careers.SO to careers.SE*

Comment: It should still get its own Meta then, imho.