# Resume PDF: Needs URL to Online Resume

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I think the feature to generate a PDF file from my resume is really great. I notice a number of details are removed to make the document more streamlined and concise.

That's great, but I don't seem to see a URL within the document to my resume online. This feature would allow the recipient to see those extra number of details, and have access to any updates I make to the resume.

I was surprised the URL isn't in the document. How about adding it?

Comment: Is there no meta for Careers?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Guess not. I clicked the link at the bottom of the Careers site to leave feedback, and it brought me here.

Comment: @Ben this very site is the meta for Careers. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230336/why-is-meta-se-the-meta-site-for-careers-so) for more details.