# Are questions on Jobs (formerly Careers) off-topic at Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, jobs, scope

From [Careers Unificintegration: Jobs on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow) it appears that the Meta site for Jobs (formerly Careers) is now [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) but I do not recall that being written here on Meta Stack Exchange in other than a comment or two.

Are questions on Jobs (formerly Careers) now off-topic here at Meta Stack Exchange?

I think they must be because some recent questions on that topic have been migrated from here to [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com):

- [Search not working on Careers, and inconsistent favourite count](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316227/search-not-working-on-careers-and-inconsistent-favourite-count)
- [Careers always reports "Last seen on Stack Overflow yesterday" in the US evenings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316009/careers-always-reports-last-seen-on-stack-overflow-yesterday-in-the-us-evening)

Looking for guidance I found [Careers needs its own meta/dedicated support system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129688/215590) but it seems concerned with arrangements for Careers rather than Jobs, and thus to be outdated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, they do belong on Meta Stack Overflow now, because Jobs is now an integrated part of the Stack Overflow site rather than a separate site floating off to the side. It wasn't widely publicized, but it was mentioned in the [original announcement for the integration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow):

> ## Want to give it a try?
>
> Jobs should be live for *everyone* now, so [go check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs). If you find bugs please post your question here on Meta Stack Overflow and tag them with the [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs) tag. We've already worked to create a job board experience that helps you put your best foot forward, but it'll get even better now that we have the chance to continue improving the experience with your help.

The "feedback always welcome" link in the footer of [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) has also been changed to link to Meta Stack Overflow rather than Meta Stack Exchange (which is where it linked previously).

The developers involved with Jobs *do* still browse Meta Stack Exchange to look for any bug reports and feature request which might have ended up here, but you shouldn't expect your question to *stay* here and most of them will end up getting migrated over to Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Meta Stack Overflow is slightly preferred, but both are okay for now while we're in a transition period.

Eventually, the developer side of Careers will be shut down and redirected to SO, and we'll probably mass-migrate all old Careers questions over to MSO. We're not quite there yet, so we're watching for questions in both places and not too worried about moving them.

Answer (score -3):

**No, they are not.**

See https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/891121?noredirect=1:

> FWIW, we monitor the 'jobs' and 'careers' tags for bug reports on both MSE and MSO. – Benjamin Hodgson♦ 13 hours ago

It's thus a surprise that a couple of people vote all these careers questions as offtopic.

Comment: Though to note, that very same question was also migrated to MSO, which is generally what will happen if you post a Jobs-related bug on MSE now.

Comment: @animuson any chance for a MSE to MSO migration path? Or are we just going to wrack up our helpful flags with "this needs to be moved"? Or one of those red box things that shows up when someone tags something with careers?