# Should [careers] be a synonym of [jobs]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, jobs, synonym-request

Previously the functionality we currently know as [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) was known as [Careers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/23/careers-2-0-launches/).

Seeing that most of the questions regarding this topic are off-topic to MSE in the first place, I don't see any value in having them spread out over several tags. The only thing that would be on-topic is the implementation of the jobs link on other technical sites like [Super User](https://superuser.com).

There are also some specific versions of [careers](/questions/tagged/careers): [careers-germany](/questions/tagged/careers-germany) [careers-city-pages](/questions/tagged/careers-city-pages) [careers-2](/questions/tagged/careers-2)(a synonym of careers). These can all be grouped together into [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs) I think.

Answer (score 10):

I agree that the tags for [careers](/questions/tagged/careers), [careers-germany](/questions/tagged/careers-germany), [careers-city-pages](/questions/tagged/careers-city-pages) and [careers-2](/questions/tagged/careers-2)(currently a synonym of careers) should all be made synonyms of [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs).

Neither questions about Stack Overflow Jobs (see [Are questions on Jobs (formerly Careers) off-topic at Meta Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274210)) or personal career questions are on-topic here at Meta Stack Exchange so keeping any that are asked grouped under just one tag ([jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs)) makes sense to me.